# How to use Multiple WhereIn queries in Firebase Android?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on an app where I'm using Cloud Firestore, at times I need to use multiple `whereIn()` queries but it's not working. Is there any way I can use multiple wherein queries or I can compare multiple list values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any way I can use multiple wherein queries or I can compare multiple list values

No, there is not.  Please read the documentation on [query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#limitations_2):

> Note the following limitations for in, not-in, and array-contains-any:
>
> - You can use **at most** one in, not-in, or array-contains-any clause per query. You can't combine these operators in the same query.

Instead, you can use a single whereIn filter, then filter the remaining results on the client app.